# Problem with Table Valued Parameter SQL server and Python Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc, table-valued-parameters

I've created a test table, then a Type Table and then a SP:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba (

    id int IDENTITY,
    datos varchar (20),
    nums NUMERIC (10,2)
    CONSTRAINT PK_PRUEBA PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TYPE dbo.pruebatable AS TABLE (

    datos varchar (20),
    nums NUMERIC (10,2)
)

CREATE PROC spruebatable
@test pruebatable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO prueba (datos,nums)
SELECT 
datos, nums
FROM @test

END;
```

And in python, I'm trying to calls this with a private connection function that works fine:

```
from haegpi import sqlconn

cursor = sqlconn()

var = ('int',1)
sql = "{CALL spruebatable (?)}"
cursor.execute (sql,var)
```

I've tried to send it as tuple, list and result is the same. Any clues?

Comment: Try `var = [('int',1)]`

Comment: Hi there Gord! I've tried that but i receive this current error : "pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Tipo de datos SQL no válido (0) (SQLBindParameter)')"

Comment: Hmm, okay … try `var = ([('int', 1)],)`

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but same same: "pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Tipo de datos SQL no válido (0) (SQLBindParameter)')" I still cant find the solution.

Comment: It appears that you are using the ancient `Driver=SQL Server` ODBC driver. Your problem should go away if you install `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` and use that instead.

Comment: Gordon, i've checked and in my client computer ODBC driver is from 2023.

Comment: `print(connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME))`. If it shows `SQLSRV32.DLL` then you are using the ancient driver regardless of the date stamp on the DLL file.

Comment: Ok Gordon. now i've managed to get something everytime i do: var = ([('int', 1)],) but i cant solve how to use it. Imagine we have this simple function: 
def var_prueba():
    mla = 'MLA12345678'
    price = 120

    return mla, price

How should i call it to make it work like you did var = ([('int', 1)],)?